# Период времени "с... по..."

Tags: смысл

Если в договоре написан период времени:"с 10 февраля 2012 года по 24 февраля 2012 года", то как это надо правильно понимать? 24 февраля входит в этот период времени или нет?

Answer (score 2):

Этот вопрос постоянно поднимается и никогда не решается доказательно в терминах значения предлога "по". Всегда приходится смотреть по контексту.
На практике обычно применяется включительное толкование, т.е. конечные даты считаются входящими в указанный интервал, и, кстати, предлог ПО здесь считается синонимичным предлогу ДО. Но при желании это толкование можно оспорить, если по контексту документа возможно иное понимание.

Answer (score 1):

по 24 февраля значит, что последний день договора истекает 23го числа. а с 24го начинается новый договор , или просто старый остаётся не в силе...если же в конце предложения поставить слово "включительно", значит, срок истечения заканчивается 24м числом.....вот так я понимаю.

Answer (score 0):

по 24 февраля - это означает что 24 февраля включительно т.е.  24 февраля последний день договора.

Answer (score 0):

Предлоги **до** и **по** далеко не синонимичны. **До** -  значит дойти до определённого места и остановиться, **по** - двигаться по определённому месту: дойти до поляны, гулять по поляне. Это значение переносится и на указание дат: **до** - до указнной даты, не включая её; **по** - включая указанную дату. ДО 24 февраля - значит последний день действия договора 23 февраля;, по 24 февраля - последний день действия договора 24 февраля.

Comment: Это вы так считаете или можете сослаться на какой-то юридически значимый документ?  
Если нет, почитайте хотя бы здесь: 
http://www.gramota.ru/spravka/hardwords/25_317

Answer (score 0):

Вообще по логике *до 24 февраля* означает *до наступления 00:00 24 февраля*. Т.е. не включая день 24 февраля. А *по 24 февраля* - включая весь день 24 февраля. С другой стороны, я нигде не видел четкого руководства что есть что и поэтому в сомнительных случаях лучше всегда указывать включается ли дата окончания. Например: *"находиться в отпуске со второго по восьмое августа включительно"*